# Angularjs remove cookie from root

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have main domain where I am storing a ng cookie upon successful login.
After successful login, the user is redirected to a sub folder. Now inside this sub folder I want to delete the cookie that was created in the root.

I'm trying `$cookieStore.remove('my_user');` but it is trying to find the cookie "my-user" in the current sub folder.

Answer (score 0):

$cookieStore service does not provide path cookies..

You should use jquery cookie https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.

Using it, you can do something like following to set and remove cookies from specific path.

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { path: '/' });
$.removeCookie('name', { path: '/' });
```